# Is there a way to generate a running within groups in?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to generate running number in dplyr using row_number but the results are not as desired. I would like to have say **cat A to have 1, 2, 3 in var1** Any leads?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  cat = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"),
  date = seq.Date(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 5,
                  by = 1),
  age = c(12, 13, 34,23,32,34)
)


df <- df %>%
  arrange(cat, date) %>%
  group_by(cat, date) %>%
  mutate(var1 = row_number())
df
```

Comment: Can you try `group_by(cat)` instead of `group_by(cat, date)`? If you're also grouping by date, you will have just one row per group...

Comment: It works as expected